# Change Background color of form in MFC resource script file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

How to change the background color of the resource script file (sample.rc)form control in MFC ,which is having controls like combo box, textbox etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is not a "form".  It is a windows dialog.  There is no resouce value you change.  You have to override the WM_ERASEBKGND message:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CDialogBackgroundDlg, CDialog)
   ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CDialogBackgroundDlg::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
   CRect r;
   pDC->GetClipBox(&r);

   pDC->FillSolidRect(r, RGB(255,0,255)); //ugly magenta background
   return TRUE;
}
```

Obviously change the class names to match yours.  In OnEraseBkgnd() you could also draw whatever kind of background you want.  It does not have to be solid.  It could be bitmap or a pattern or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.


This is the way i call dialogwindow inside the main window.The main window consists of opengl one part and dialog window another.So in this situation how can i change
the background color of dialog window alone.

Comment: Main.cpp
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR cmdArgs, int cmdShow)
{Win::DialogWindow glDialog(hInst, IDD_FORMVIEW, mainWin.getHandle(), &formCtrl); glDialog.show();}

Comment: You tagged your question with MFC, but your code here in this comment is anything but MFC.  What framework are you actually using?

Comment: Here i am using VC++ project.This project is combination of opengl and resource script files.So the main window consists of half opengl which is having viewport and another half is resoource script file or resource dialog(i.e sampleproject.rc)having  controls like chekcbox,button etc.
i have added the following lines in sampledialog.cpp

Comment: `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(sampledialog, CDialog)
      ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
        ON_WM_PAINT()
        ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
        //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
        ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()`
`BOOL DialogWindow::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        CBrush myBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));             // dialog background color
        CBrush *pOld = pDC->SelectObject(&myBrush);
        BOOL bRes = pDC->PatBlt(0, 0, rect.Width(), rect.Height(), PATCOPY);
        pDC->SelectObject(pOld); 
        return bRes;            CDialog::OnEraseBkgnd(pDC);
}`

Comment: when i compile , it throws following errors,
C1189: #error :  WINDOWS.H already included.  MFC apps must not #include <windows.h> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxv_w32.h 16 1 sampleproject
                   error C1189: #error : This file requires _WIN32_WINNT to be #defined at least to 0x0403. Value 0x0501 or higher is recommended. c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlwinverapi.h 29 1 sampleproject
pls help me to resolove this errors...